# How to set PropType for an objectOf either strings or functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, material-ui, react-proptypes

I have a prop which is an object of strings and functions. I attempted to set proptypes as

```
component.propTypes = {
  propName: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.func])
}
```

However that doesn't seem to work as I'm getting and error saying that it reads the inside parameter as '[object Object]'. How can define the prop as an object of either string or function?

TMI. This is for Material UI's sx prop, and I'm not using TypeScript in my project

Answer (score 0):

I use `sx` and in my definitions it's just an object.

```js
component.propTypes = {
  propName: PropTypes.object
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but eslint reports that as a forbidden propType, since it's so generic. I was wondering whether it could be more specific, i.e. string or function